# App Store не разрешает постить фото ВК?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, appstore

Получил отказ при обновлении приложения по такой причине:

> 22.4 Details
>
> Also, your app falls into a category of apps that are often used for
>   illegal file sharing, which does not comply with the App Store Review
>   Guidelines. Specifically, app provides access to streaming media
>   content (music and movies) posted on VKontakte social network. We’ve
>   attached screenshot(s) for your reference.

До этого пропускали. В приложении постятся полученные фотографии на стену VK, кто знает как угодить App Store, чтобы функция осталась?

Они приложили свои скриншоты:

https://yadi.sk/i/1oZguYoFh7YLZ

https://yadi.sk/i/8SKpKqz6h7YLf

https://yadi.sk/i/bZC1nGX1h7YLb

Приложение работает так: при нажатии ВкАктивити появляется окно для ввода логина пароля как на скриншоте (если введёшь, то пост автоматом на стену будет размещен), а если его не вводить, а использовать в этом окне, можно выйти на главную страницу Вк и использовать сайт по полной (фильмы и музыку проигрывать), вот поэтому Apple даёт отворот поворот!

Comment: Судя по тексту, у них претензии не к приложению, а к самому VK...

Comment: У меня была такая же проблема. С вкактивити не пропускали. Вк у них находится в черном списке. @klopp верно сказал.

Answer (score 1):

ВК доработали своё SDK. Теперь такого нет, обновлять ничего не нужно.

Проблема была связана с тем, что во время авторизации через VK SDK можно было пройти на сторонние странички, где уже была музыка и тому подобное. Теперь такой возможности не будет.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).

Comment: Обновил ответ, теперь должно быть более понятно. Код приложения менять не нужно, поэтому его и в ответе нет.